How to generate all proto files at the same time
I have several proto files, How to generate all proto files at the same time?
What code should I write in the script section to generate all the proto files together?
"scripts": {
"dev": "next dev -p 3003",
"proto-gen": "node ./proto-gen.js --proto=./proto,./generated,token.proto "
},
It generates only one file, But I want all the proto files
I have several proto files, How to generate all proto files at the same time?

Can you provide a reference for proto-gen.js? I'm unfamiliar with proto-gen.js but, you may be able to specify multiple proto files by repeating the --proto flag i.e. --proto=a.proto --proto=b.proto ...
